# Doctrine's DBAL query builder omitts some joins

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

**PHP CODE:**

```php
    $xCodesQueryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();

    $xCodesQueryBuilder->select("l.id","mdsh.xcode","mdso.xcode")
            ->from("location_tree","l")
            ->join("l","location_tree_pos","p","l.id = p.tree_id")
            ->rightJoin("l","hotel","h","h.location_id = l.id")
            ->leftJoin("l","offer_location","ol","l.id=ol.location_id")
            ->leftJoin("ol","mds_offer","mdso","ol.offer_id = mdso.offer_id")
            ->leftJoin("h","mds_hotel","mdsh","h.id = mdsh.hotel_id")
            ->where("p.parent_id IN (:ids)")
            ->andWhere("(mdso.xcode IS NOT NULL OR mdsh.xcode IS NOT NULL)");

    var_dump($xCodesQueryBuilder->getSQL());exit;
```

**RESULT:**

```sql
SELECT l.id, mdsh.xcode, mdso.xcode
FROM location_tree l 
INNER JOIN location_tree_pos p ON l.id = p.tree_id 
RIGHT JOIN hotel h ON h.location_id = l.id 
LEFT JOIN offer_location ol ON l.id=ol.location_id 
WHERE (p.parent_id IN (:ids)) 
AND ((mdso.xcode IS NOT NULL OR mdsh.xcode IS NOT NULL))
```

Any ideas why 2 last joins are omitted?

Comment: for some reaseon every first argument to join must be the same ("l" in my case) and then it works. Can anybody explain logic behind this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Only those joins that are associated with the "FROM" table alias appear. Everything else seems to get omitted.

Answer (score 3):

I just got this working for me. Had to modify the function `getSQLForSelect()` in `QueryBuilder.php`.

I've opened up a [ticket](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DBAL-172) and submitted a pull request to DBAL, but in the meanwhile, feel free to use [my patched copy](https://github.com/anushr/dbal/blob/patch-1/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Query/QueryBuilder.php).

**UPDATE:**

Just realized that an alternate way to fix this issue is to always use the `FROM` table alias as the first argument (`$fromAlias`) in any of the `join()` methods.

In your case, you'd change your code to look like this:

```php
$xCodesQueryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();

$xCodesQueryBuilder->select("l.id","mdsh.xcode","mdso.xcode")
        ->from("location_tree","l")
        ->join("l","location_tree_pos","p","l.id = p.tree_id")
        ->rightJoin("l","hotel","h","h.location_id = l.id")
        ->leftJoin("l","offer_location","ol","l.id=ol.location_id")
        ->leftJoin("l","mds_offer","mdso","ol.offer_id = mdso.offer_id")
        ->leftJoin("l","mds_hotel","mdsh","h.id = mdsh.hotel_id")
        ->where("p.parent_id IN (:ids)")
        ->andWhere("(mdso.xcode IS NOT NULL OR mdsh.xcode IS NOT NULL)");

var_dump($xCodesQueryBuilder->getSQL());exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Doctrine 2.3.1 is supporting this.

A way around could be converting joins to from and where, use group by if required.
Got stuck for 2-3 hours, finally used this workaround
because even after upgrading doesn't helped me (trying to figure out why)